# Short Range Wireless Protocol History

Tags: wireless

When did numerous short-range wireless protocols start showing up? I know Bluetooth was first invented by Ericsson in 1994 from reading up resources on the Internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would really like a book on the history of electronics engineering. I mean, I have read many on Computing and such but found nothing on electronics

Comment: @Rick_2047 - That sounds like a good question.

Answer (score 5):

The Infrared Data Association (IrDA) was established in 1993, I guess you could call their standards a type of wireless.

Comment: Albeit infrared isn't very popular other than in remote controls. It may be dead fairly soon anyway from some articles I've read.

Comment: @stanigator: IR dying out? Where did you hear that?

Comment: @stanigator: Your question was about short range wireless protocols. IrDA is a short range wireless protocol. This is actually a pretty good answer considering IR is one of the earlier forms of wireless communication.

Answer (score 3):

[This document](http://www.jacksons.net/working%20papers/Dynamic%20Sharing%20%202002%20version.pdf) may give you some pointers. It discusses the sharing of radio frequencies, which is needed for this kind of radio communication.

Comment: I wonder whether any consideration has been given to the notion of having some frequencies reserved for devices seeking to 'sync up', with more stringent duty-cycle restrictions than would be applied to 'general use' frequencies, or to the notion of requiring cell providers to transmit a quickly-readable time signal synced with WWV (which is precise, but really slow).  Sharing frequencies is great for devices that have synchronized clocks, but doesn't really work well otherwise.